# Is there a way for me to combine DialogFlow with HTML Web Speech API?

Tags: dialogflow-es, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, webspeech-api

I am creating a speech recognition + synthesis platform through the browser using webkit speech API. I was wondering if there was a way to capture Dialog flow's agent response and then run it through web speech API.

For example, I've built a chatbot in DialogFlow. Now I want to combine that with Web Speech API so that if I ask the correct question in the browser, it will speak the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate a bit about your use case? I'm asking because Dialogflow has also connections with Speech API and the intent response may be synthesized too.

So basically you don't need to "redo" it.